# My flag isnt catching, it only returns the first possible. Im trying to take a string and add a D after it if its a digit and a X if it isnt

Tags: python, loops

```
def inBetweenAdv(var1):  #this is the input
    total = ""  
    isit = False    # my flag
    for i in var1:  
        if (i.isdigit):   #trying to see if i is a digit or not
            isit = True  
            if isit:  
                total = total + str(i) + "D"  
            if isit == False:  
                total = total +str(i) + "X"  
    return total
```

Comment: `i.isdigit` is the method itself - `i.isdigit()` calls it... Also, how would `if isit == False` (should be `if not isit`) ever evaluate truth-y, given that you **literally just assigned** `isit = True`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use isdigit() you will get an error, because int and float don't have isdigit() method, unless you want to validate something like "3", but then is not neccesary to convert i in string. You are trying to put a flag but the methods can be used like flags for example if i.isdigit() will return True with isinstance is the same if i is int or float the sentence will evaluate True or False.

```
    def inBetweenAdv(var1):
        total = ""  
        for i in var1:  
            if isinstance(i, int) or isinstance(i, float):   
                total = total + str(i) + "D"  
            else:  
                total = total +str(i) + "X"  
        return total
```

I guess this is what you want to do. But I'm not sure that you want to return a string with all the values together, I guess you want a list to be returned. In that case is:

```
    def inBetweenAdv(var1):
        lst = []  
        for i in var1:  
            if isinstance(i, int) or isinstance(i, float):   
                lst.append(str(i) + "D")  
            else:  
                lst.append(str(i) + "X")  
        return lst
```